# Regex match from ... until

Tags: regex, ansible

I have a strings similar to the below:

```
Secret key\r\nKey: \r\nNew key is: car!5\r\nKey added
Secret key\r\nKey: \r\nNew key is: 123fruit2!!\r\nKey added
Secret key\r\nKey: \r\nNew key is: ChairS5!#\r\nKey added
```

I would like to match what is between "is:" and , in the examples above the expected matches would be

```
car!5
123fruit2!!
ChairS5!#
```

What I've come up with so far is as follows:

```
is:([^\\\\]*){3}\s*
(?:is:)*([^\\\\]*){3}
```

But it fails to fetch the results expected

Comment: Use `(?<=is: ).+` - in Ansible.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I tried the following:

  - set_fact:
      getkey: "{{ getkey_raw.stdout_lines[2] | regex_search(regexp,'\\1') }}"
    vars:
      regexp: '(?<=is: ).+' 

But in doing so I receive an error msg "IndexError: no such group"

Comment: Sure, if you need to capture the result use a simpler `is:\s*(.+)`